# KB3132372 causes dotnet embedded browsercontrol to crash on sites containing flash

Tags: .net, flash, browser, crash

It appears that KB3132372 has undesirable side-effects in terms of the .net web browser embedded control. If one creates a simple form which contains a web browser control and instructs it (either programmatically or manually by means of Ctrl+O) to navigate to a url like:

https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html
http://sellercentral.amazon.com

Then a hard-crash occurs on the process and event-log is created in the windows event-logs. Non-flash websites are working fine. I was wondering if anyone has found a decent workaround (other than uninstalling the update and/or uninstalling the flash-dlls alltogether from the system).

P.S.: I've created the following bug-report in the IE bugtracker. If there's a better place to report this issue please feel free to give me a tip:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/2203846/kb3132372-causes-dotnet-embedded-browsercontrol-to-crash-on-sites-containing-flash

Update: Folks at MS responded the following:

We identified this issue previously and currently we are investigating this issue further. For more information please visit:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3132372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft issued another update (KB3133431) which apparently resolves the issue at hand.